# Azure DevOps CI Build Pipeline Fails After Adding Font Awesome Pro

Tags: angular, azure-pipelines, font-awesome

I have an Angular 14 app and recently had to add Font Awesome Pro 6.  I was able to install FA Pro locally and run without any issues.  However, when I pushed by changes up to the repo and the CI Pipeline ran, it failed with a 404 error.  I assumed this was due to the recent change (adding FA Pro).

I found suggestions to add an `.npmrc` file in the same folder as the `package.json`.  I added that file with this content (my token redacted, obviously):

```
@fortawesome:registry=https://npm.fontawesome.com
//npm.fontawesome.com/:_authToken=$<mytokenhere>
```

This has gotten me past the original 404 error and now I am getting this output from the build pipeline:

```
npm ERR! Incorrect or missing password.
npm ERR! If you were trying to login, change your password, create an
npm ERR! authentication token or enable two-factor authentication then
npm ERR! that means you likely typed your password in incorrectly.
npm ERR! Please try again, or recover your password at:
npm ERR!     https://www.npmjs.com/forgot
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you were doing some other operation then your saved credentials are
npm ERR! probably out of date. To correct this please try logging in again with:
npm ERR!     npm login

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\npm\cache\_logs\2022-11-29T02_19_35_677Z-debug-0.log
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, FA has a page that documents how to do this (properly) here: https://fontawesome.com/docs/web/setup/packages?

The problem is (I am ashamed to admit) that when I hard coded the token into the `.npmrc` file, I left the leading `$`.  That would only be needed if I was using a variable like `${api_token_variable}`.  So chalk this one up to user error (and not enough sleep).

Comment: Glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue. You could Accept it as an Answer , it could help other community members who get the same issues issue to find the solution easily.

Comment: @DouXu-MSFT I have accepted it, thank you.